# What is a full-stack framework?

Tags: frameworks

I want to build a full-stack framework out of different libraries. **What should the layers be in order to make a developer happy?** DB? DOs? Admin? API generation? Dynamic rest? UI? Android? SDK? ObjC? JS? UI? Multiple UIs? User management? Authentication? Authorization? Security? Encryption? etc.

I found some [examples of full-stack frameworks in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework#History) but the page lacks the definition and requirements of such a framework.

So what is a full-stack framework?

What are the **requirements/layers** of a framework to be called full-stack?

Comment: Sounds like a marketing term.  Or do you think there's some standards body that will come after your ass if you call something "full-stack" when it's only 3/4-stack?

Comment: @Will - Why the negativity? What do you think is a full-stack framework?

Comment: If you check the [tour], "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."  Defining marketing terms doesn't really qualify.

Comment: @Will - I want to build a full-stack framework out of different libraries. **What should the layers be in order to make a developer happy**? DB? DO? Admin? API generation? Dynamic rest? UI? Android? SDK? ObjC? JS? UI? Multiple UIs? User management? etc.

Comment: That's a better question.  You might want to add details about your requirements in an [edit].  Sounds borderline on topic, tho.  Try and see.

Comment: Updated the question. It's a hard one. Hard one to ask. Is it the requirements/features of a product, separated into layers, meaning from dev POV?

Answer (score 1):

A full stack development means  performing tasks at any level of the technical stack in which they reside. It means:
Working with systems infrastructure (knowing what hardware to ask for , what OS to install, how to prepare the system and dependencies for all software)
Understanding, creating, manipulating, and querying databases
API / back-end code in one or more languages, e.g. Ruby, Java, Python, etc.
Front-end code in one or more languages, e.g. HTML, JavaScript, Java, etc.
Project management / client work, e.g. gathering requirements, creating technical specifications and architecture documents, creating good documentation, managing a project timeline (e.g., someone who knows Agile/SCRUM/Kanban)

In general a full-stack developer has knowledge that is a mile wide, but not necessarily very deep, and has core competencies in the pieces of the stack in which they work most.

In my work I have core competencies in Linux (Debian, CentOS, Amazon Linux), Database design, manipulation, and query (PSQL and MySQL), back-end technologies (Java, Ruby, and Python), and some front-end design (HTML, vanilla JavaScript, and jQuery), as well as act as SCRUM-master and lead Agile development for my team, interfacing with clients both internal and external to the business to gather requirements, execute tasks, and document all efforts.

Typically these skills are developed over many years in the contexts of different jobs, so as Ian mentioned being a full-stack developer means being pushed outside of your comfort zone to constantly learn new skills.

Answer (score 1):

I may be a bit late but a full stack framework means that you can build the totality of your app with (or within) the framework.

If we talk about JS frameworks, you have the client-side frameworks ([React](https://fr.reactjs.org/), [Vue](https://vuejs.org/)...) and the server-side ([NestJs](https://nestjs.com/), [Express](https://expressjs.com/fr/)...). A few like [CASE](https://case.app) are taking the full stack angle combining front AND back.

**What are the requirements/layers of a framework to be called full-stack?**

I would say some database management (DB logic, ORM), entity logic, routing and templating are the key features in web development for a full-stack framework.